# Vue js : Filter dynamic data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Vuejs below I want to filter the `reviewed:true` only questions, and get the length of them, but my code below gives an error `TypeError: question.reviewed.includes is not a function` ,is there a way to do it?

Here is the screenshot about the json file:
[JSON File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/641J0.png)

```js
 filterReviewed() {
      return this.questions.filter((question) => {
        return (
            question.reviewed
            .includes('true')
        );
      });
    },
```

Comment: It seems `reviewed` is a property of `question`. `return this.questions.filter((question) => question.reviewed)`. No need for `includes`.

Comment: Review is not a string property instead it is a boolean property. Try it as ```return this.questions.filter((question) => question.reviewed)```

Answer (score 1):

`includes` is a method of Object of `Array` type. Directly judge attribute `reviewed` is OK

```
filterReviewed (){
  return this.questions.filter((question) => question.reviewed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter the reviews try this:

```
filterReviewed() {
          return this.questions.filter((question) => question.reviewed === true);
        },
```

To get the filterReviewed length try this:

```
filterReviewed.questions.length
```

Comment: i tried your answer the filter works properly but i apply the length condition here it's not working        ` <div
            class="showmore-Div"
            v-show="
              commentsToShow < filterReviewed.length||
                  filterReviewed.length > commentsToShow
            "
          >
            <button @click="commentsToShow += 10" class="showMore-Button">
              show more
            </button>
          </div>`

Comment: * commentsToShow: 25,

Comment: If you try this? `filterReviewed.questions.length`. ?